# add checkboxes in twitter bootstrap dropdown

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i am using twitter bootstrap for my project.

I want to add checkboxes in dropdown, something similar to http://jsfiddle.net/qG7c4/

File: bootstrap-dropdown.js

Example: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns

problem is, that dropdown get closed on click of every checkbox, i don't want this to be closed on click of checkbox, so that user can select multiple checkboxes easily.

What changes i need to do in javascript for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try stopping the propagation of the click event on your input elements like so:

```
$('.dropdown-menu input, .dropdown-menu label').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qG7c4/9/)